# CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set

Tags: cmake, nest

I am trying to install nest simulator from source in miniconda3 (I have ubuntu), but when I reach to this code:

`cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX /home/atiye/Downloads/nest-simulator-3.5`

I face with this error:

CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Can you help me to remove this error?

I checked Cmake installation, I have it.
I also use this code:
`cmake  /home/atiye/Downloads/nest-simulator-3.5 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C-compiler -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C++-compiler`

But Still have this error:
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Comment: A build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles" is `make`. Do you have it installed?